set context language 'admin-extension-sdk' shopware
I have a language dropdown and want to fetch products based on the selected language. In the documentation, I see the following:
const language = await sw.context.getLanguage();
However, how do I set the language when the language is switched?

Please provide us with a code example of what you are trying to achieve
